# How would you ask opinions for differences between two things?

Tags: questions, politeness

I want to ask politely for an in-depth explanation of how these two apparently similar things A and B are different when closely looked at.

Eg: "In which way A and B are different from each other?"

Comment: “I know A and B are very similar, but I was wondering if you could explain some of the details on how they differ.”

Comment: *How are A and B different from each other?*

Comment: Or, *To what extent are A and B similar?*

Comment: Note OP asks for “polite”.  The questions proposed in comments and answers certainly get the intention across but they do Not have any added elements of politeness.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to tell that including what Justin has mentioned in the comments. I'd also add one more to it especially when you mean that there are little **but significant** differences -

> What are the [*subtle differences*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/subtle) between A and B?